# Auto start an app when charger is plugged

Tags: java, android

I will make a new Android application. How to to auto-start it as soon as the mobile is plugged into charging?

If this is successfully done, then the application will be opened automatically when the charger is plugged to the mobile phone.

Comment: What do you mean with "start"? You mean you want an activity to pop-up?

Comment: thank you for your answer. I mean that "the application will be opened automatically when the charger is plugged to the mobile phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a broadcast receiver for this.

Add this to your manifest:

```
 <receiver android:name=".PowerConnectionReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
  </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Now add this to your class

```
public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
    int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
    boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING || 
                                status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;



    int chargePlug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
    boolean usbCharging = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
    boolean acCharging = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;

    if (isCharging) {

       Intent i = new Intent();
       i.setClassName("com.className", "com.classname.YourActivityClass");
       i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       context.startActivity(i)
    }

 }
}
```

Don't forget to replace things like com.className with yours.

Comment: This won't work on Android 8.0+, on which there is (deliberately) no way to do this. See https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts